formatting input value as a tuple
I want to post form data like the following:
<input hidden data-tagid="1" data-boolean="1" name="tagswithboolean[]" value="1,1">
<input hidden data-tagid="2" data-boolean="1" name="tagswithboolean[]" value="2,1">
<input hidden data-tagid="3" data-boolean="2" name="tagswithboolean[]" value="3,2">

What is the proper formatting for value in order to create an enumerable list of tuples named tagswithboolean, posting to a json object?
